# How to add 2 Section Headers in Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to to add 2 Section Headers in Recycler View..
I want to develop Header inside a Header.
I dont want to use Expandable view.I need it in Scroll-able view.

I want to show Tour Name as 1st Header.
Under that i want to show Location as 2nd Header

[image]

Comment: can u explain me in detail plz

Comment: Please clarify what you exactly want to develop

Comment: this provable Github links is Develop a Expands and Collapse @Satya

Comment: I see that question is edited..so removed my comments

Comment: i want to create 2 headers in one List itselt..

Comment: u want to a header after Device 1 Name and after Device 2 name ? @OmkarJaveri

Comment: No i want tour name as 1st header and Location name as second Header under location the device list will be shown..i have multiple tour names under these i have many locations which are having multiple devices..-@MohammadAli

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P033M.jpg **See this image u want to like this??**

Comment: look at any library, I think it helps you, for example: [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using different view types in `RecyclerView`.

Firstly, You need to pass a list of objects to your recycler view adapter that specify whether the data should be used as a section header or not.

Here's an example of that data class.

```
// In a fuller example, this would probably hold more data than just strings.
public class SectionOrRow {

    private String row;
    private String section;
    private boolean isRow;

    public static SectionOrRow createRow(String row) {
        SectionOrRow ret = new SectionOrRow();
        ret.row = row;
        ret.isRow = true;
        return ret;
    }

    public static SectionOrRow createSection(String section) {
        SectionOrRow ret = new SectionOrRow();
        ret.section = section;
        ret.isRow = false;
        return ret;
    }

    public String getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public boolean isRow() {
        return isRow;
    }
}
```

Create data list of these objects with `SectionOrRow.createRow("a normal row")` or `SectionOrRow.createSection("a section header")`, and the `isRow` **boolean** is set accordingly.

Define the `getItemViewType` method in adapter, which tells recycler view there will be two types, a **row type** and a **section type**, and we'll specify which position these are in by looking at the `isRow` boolean in above data object.

Here's an example of Adapter class.

```
public class SectionRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SECTION = 0;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    private List<SectionOrRow> mData;

    public MyRecycler(List<SectionOrRow> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public class RowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView textView;
        public RowViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }

    public class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView textView;
        public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType==VIEW_TYPE_SECTION) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            return new SectionViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            return new RowViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SectionOrRow item = mData.get(position);
        if(item.isRow()) {
            RowViewHolder h = (RowViewHolder) holder;
            h.textView.setText(item.getRow());
        } else {
            SectionViewHolder h = (SectionViewHolder) holder;
            h.textView.setText(item.getSection());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        super.getItemViewType(position);
        SectionOrRow item = mData.get(position);
        if(!item.isRow()) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_SECTION;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }        

}
```

In this example, It's just using the standard `simple_list_item_1` for both but with a blue text background for the section. You can change raw and section layouts as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a list of objects to your adapter that specify whether the data is getting inserted of not.
Add a debugger and test it.